# Map single json property for each item in a list

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and I am using **Angular 14**

**1- JSON response** :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "abbreviation": "ATL",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "conference": "East",
            "division": "Southeast",
            "full_name": "Atlanta Hawks",
            "name": "Hawks"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "abbreviation": "BOS",
            "city": "Boston",
            "conference": "East",
            "division": "Atlantic",
            "full_name": "Boston Celtics",
            "name": "Celtics"
        }
}
```

**- Model Interface :**

```
export interface TeamResponse{
    data: Team[];
}
```

**- Team Interface :**

```
export interface Team{
    id: Number;
    abbreviation: string;
    city: string;
    conference: string;
    division: string;
    name: string;
    fullName: string; // I wan to map this to full_name json property
}
```

**- Service**:

```
getTeams(): Observable<TeamResponse>{
   return this.http.get<TeamResponse>(this.teamsServiceURL);
}
```

**- Component Typescript File:**

```
export class TeamSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedTeam! : Team;
  teams : Team[] = [];

  constructor(private teamService:TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe({
      next: (response: TeamResponse) => {
        this.teams = response.data;
      },
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
  })
    
  }

}
```

Everything works file except for the **fullName** property in **Team interface** since I want to map it to **full_name** in **json**.

What is the best way to map full_name to fullName instead of easily using full_name in the interface ?

since this naming convention is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not access to your API you can change a bit your service to return an array of Teams

For this, use "map" in your service to return an array of Team

```
getTeams(): Observable<Team[]>{
   return this.httpClient.get<Team[]>(this.teamsServiceURL).pipe(
      map((res:any)=>{
        return res.data.map((x:any)=>({
          ...x,
          fullName:x.full_name  //<--see this line
        }))
      })
   )
}
```

And change the component call to service to be as follows :

```
this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe({
      next: (response: Team[]) => {
        this.teams = response;
      },
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
    })
```

Equal, when you search an unique Team you also use map, I imagine some like

```
getTeam(id:number){
   return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
      map((res:any)=>({
          ...x,
          fullName:x.data.full_name  //<--see this line
        }))
   )
}
```

NOTE: If you have access to your API, sure you can make that return fullName and not full_name, e.g. in .NET you can [customize property names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

Comment: is there's any other solution rather than map the response to any ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Really the function should be defined as: `getTeams():Observable<Team[]>` and `getTeam(id:number):Observable<Team>`. The "map((res:any)=>.." (Be carefull, I update the code for the getTemas function -before I wrote `any[]` and it was wrong) is necessary: you have no interface with "full_name"

Comment: ok I changed the getTeams to return Observable<Team[]> and it works fine can you change the comment or can I change it to accept the answer ?

Comment: ,ok I changed the answer a little bit can you please review before I accept it to make sure it match the recommendation and standers of Angular and Typescript ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, I like your changes. But I would prefer use the name `httpClient`instead of `http` to help to understand that we need inject HttpClient not the old Http (equal in another places I whould prefer activatedRoute in stead route when we should inject ActivatedRoute, or domSanitizer instead of sanitizer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in typescript. But, I guess its expecting the both keys should be same in json and interface for fullName.

my suggestion, avoid using underscore instead try using camelCase.

Comment: This is an easy not recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
getTeams(): Observable<Team>{
   return this.http.get<TeamResponse>(this.teamsServiceURL).pipe(
      map((teams) => teams.map(
          team => {
              return {
                 ...team,
                 fullName: team.full_name 
              }
          }
      ))
   );
}
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'TeamResponse' although map is imported

Comment: sorry, the types should be arrays. `TeamResponse` -> `TeamResponse[]` and `Team` -> `Team[]`. The first map is `rxjs` `map` operator which takes in an observable stream and converts values emitted. Here the input stream is `TeamResponse[]` and we convert it to `Team[]`. The second map is an `array` method. You give it a callback and it returns a new array by calling the callback function on every element to convert it.